# newline between 2 tags causes whitespace in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a working HTML/CSS code for a button selector.

You can see it at http://jsfiddle.net/NnR6d/

The HTML code is

```
<div>
    <button>Button 1
    </button><button>Button 2</button>
</div>
```

And the CSS code is

```
button{
    margin:0;
    border:none;
    background:green;
}
```

Today, I wanted to organize the HTML code. so I changed it to this

```
<div>
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
</div>
```

and I was amazed to discover the UI broke! Now I have a space between the buttons.

You can see the broken UI at http://jsfiddle.net/NnR6d/1/

I know the cause for this is a "space" character created once I added a newline between the close tag for the first button and the open tag for the second button.

but this seems wrong. I don't think it should have affected my design.

Is there a CSS to reset this behavior? Is there a way to tell the browser to not add this whitespace?

Comment: _"but this seems wrong"_ Why? Inline elements are sensitive to white space. Simply remove it http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/NnR6d/2/

Comment: You could set the font property of the parent to `0/0 a` to remove inside text, and then reset that for the button elements e.g.: `16px/1 Arial`

Comment: @Klaster_1 - thank you for referencing that question. My question does seem to be a duplicate. What is the proper way to handle this in stackoverflow?

Comment: You can delete the question or wait until it gets closed by moderators.

Answer (score 1):

`float:left` on the button CSS would solve this I believe, althought it may cause a whole bunch of other problems depending on the rest of your HTML